# Get controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In WebApiConfig.cs i have the following

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); 

   config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),
               new MyApiControllerSelector(config));

   //code omitted for brevity
}
```

then in the **MyApiControllerSelector.cs** i want to get the controller

```
public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {           
            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();           

            var controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

            //code omitted for brevity
        }
```

Pretty simple and it worked great but now using **attribute routing** i think it needs a different approach? - as i can't seem to find a simple way

I've tried

```
var controllerName = request.GetActionDescriptor().ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
```

which doesn't work.

Then reading the [source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs) with debugging lead me to `request.GetRouteData().Values["MS_SubRoutes"]`

So now I have

```
string subRoutesKey = "MS_SubRoutes";

var attributedRoutesData = routeData.Values[subRoutesKey] as IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData>; 
var subRouteData = attributedRoutesData.FirstOrDefault();

var actions = (ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor[])subRouteData.Route.DataTokens["actions"];
var controllerName = actions[0].ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
```

which works but it has to be a simpler way?

**UPDATE**

@KiranChalla asked what's my use case so i'm posting the remaining code. 
Basically i'm parsing version media type `Accept: application/vnd.app.{resource}.v{version}+json` from request and returning a **HttpControllerDescriptor** depending on the version.

```
            HttpControllerDescriptor oldControllerDescriptor;
            if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerName, out oldControllerDescriptor))
            {
                var apiVersion = GetVersionFromMediaType(request);

                var newControllerName = String.Concat(controllerName, "V", apiVersion);

                HttpControllerDescriptor newControllerDescriptor;
                if (controllers.TryGetValue(newControllerName, out newControllerDescriptor))
                {                    
                    return newControllerDescriptor;
                }               
                return oldControllerDescriptor;
            }
            return null;
```

Comment: I believe there is no other simpler way that I am aware of. Just fyi...a small improvement, you can do `request.GetRouteData().GetSubRoutes()` to get list attribute routes...

Comment: By the way, Can you describe what your scenario is? I am curious to know how you intend to use custom controller selector with attribute routing.

Comment: @KiranChalla Thanks for the suggestion. I've explained my scenario and added the remaining code so please take a look and correct me if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: @KiranChalla can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835015/versioning-asp-net-web-api-2-with-media-types

Comment: Curiously, DefaultHttpControllerSelector has a GetControllerName method that also fails on sub routes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As confirmed by @KiranChalla there is no simpler way then the one I've already implemented, except the minor suggestion to use `GetSubRoutes()`

```
var attributedRoutesData = request.GetRouteData().GetSubRoutes();
var subRouteData = attributedRoutesData.FirstOrDefault();

var actions = (ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor[])subRouteData.Route.DataTokens["actions"];
var controllerName = actions[0].ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
```

Comment: @ainteger No, it's just a different approach to get the necessary data (controller name) from the pipeline.

Comment: The suggestion of using `GetSubRoutes()` is an excellent one. It's the approach I've taken because using `MS_SubRoutes` is reliance on an undocumented string literal that could easily change without warning in the future.

Answer (score 0):

its old ticket but i get controller name this way,

```
 var ControllerName = context.Request.RouteValues.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
```