# Custom controller selector and attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

I develop WebAPI application and I need to use a custom controller selector, so I have created this one:

```
public class CustomControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    (...)
    
    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        // It's just a simplified logic which exemplify the problem
        var controller =_controllerAssembly.GetType("App.Controllers.MyController");
        return new HttpControllerDescriptor(this.httpConfiguration, controller.Name, controller);
    }
}
```

My controller contains two GET methods:

```
public class MyController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/myController/GetAll")]
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAll(){ ... }

    public MyModel Get(){ ... }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I go to *http://localhost/api/myController/*, I get the error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>
> GetAll on type App.Controllers.MyController
>
> Get on type App.Controllers.MyController"

But if I go to *http://localhost/api/myController/GetAll*, it works as intended and collection of object is returned.

It is worth mentioning that if I don't use the custom controller selector, it works like a charm and both actions gives valid response.

Do you know why *custom controller selector* (derived from default selector) causes this problem?

**Workaround:**

Since the original (default) controller selector is initialized properly and works as expected, I aggregate it instead of inherit from it.

```
class CustomControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector 
{ 
    private DefaultHttpControllerSelector defaultSelector; 

    public CustomControllerSelector(DefaultHttpControllerSelector defaultSelector)
    { 
        (...) 
}
```

Comment: Also `http://localhost/api/myController/get` will work. Yes?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because I use default WebAPI routing configuration: `
`config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); (...) routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}" (...)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't mention that I had also `Get(int id)` action. Nevertheless, I remove this method and I get the same result as I described in my post (`api/myController/get` causes error if I use custom selector, otherwise it works properly).

Comment: Dose not `MyController` inherited from `ApiController` in your project?

Comment: Actually, it does. I've corrected my post.

Comment: For a test put this rout attribute over Get method and run:  `[Route("~/api/myController/Get")]`

Comment: OK, I did that.
`api/myController/Get` works properly;
`api/myController/GetAll` works properly;
`api/myController/` doesn't work (error _Multiple actions..._ is displayed)

Comment: I suggest you read this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835015/versioning-asp-net-web-api-2-with-media-types). Follow it. I hope it help.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked it, but I've not found the satisfying answer. Nevertheless, it's helped me to find the workaround.