# HttpControllerSelector not working with Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I'm using a custom HTTP controller selector to version my API.

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceSelector(config));
```

Below is my controller with actions:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/messages")]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("unreadall")] // api/v1/messages/unreadall
    public IEnumerable<long> UnreadAll()
    {
      // Return value;
    }
    [Route("{type}/unreadall")] // api/v1/messages/{type}/unreadall
    public IEnumerable<long> UnreadAll(string type)
    {
      // Return value;
    }
    [Route("unreadnext")] // api/v1/messages/unreadnext
    public long UnreadNext()
    {
      // Return value;
    }
    [Route("{type/}unreadnext")] // api/v1/messages/{type}/unreadnext
    public long UnreadNext(string type)
    {
      // Return value;
    }
    [Route("{id:long}/markasread")] // api/v1/messages/123/markasread
    [HttpPut]
    public string MarkAsRead(long id)
    {
        // Return value;
    }
    [Route("{id:long}")] // Default Action
    public string Get(long id) // api/v1/messages/123
    {
        // Return value;
    }
    [Route("")] // Default Action
    [HttpPost]
    public long Post(string message) // api/v1/messages
    {
        // Return value;
    }
}
```

Below is my route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi1",
                routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
            );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi2",
                routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{action}"
            );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I test my routes, the following work.

```
/api/v1/messages/unreadall
/api/v1/messages/unreadnext
/api/v1/messages/123/markasread
```

But the below routes, also point to the same actions.

```
/api/v1/messages/type/unreadall
/api/v1/messages/type/unreadnext
```

And I get errors for the rest of my routes.

```
/api/v1/messages/123
Error:
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59411/api/v1/messages/123'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'MessagesController' that matches the name '123'."
}

POST: /api/v1/messages
Error:
{
    "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
}
```

Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong with my route configuration ? or can someone please post working route configuration for my scenarios above ?

Appreciate your help !

Cheers,

Comment: How the custom controller code maybe? That's the most relevant part of your code.

Comment: Mihai, I'm using the exact controller code from this link  http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/dd207952fa86#Samples/WebApi/NamespaceControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting it's the expected behavior: the routes defined in **route config** *works*, while the **attribute routes** *does not*.

This happens because `request.GetRouteData()` is **not** taking into account *attribute routes*. This makes sense of course because there is no specific *controller* that a route points to as attributed routes are related to *methods*, not *controllers*.

When you use attribute routing, all the **route attributes** get added to a common route *without a name*. This is a **special route** that is an instance of an internal class called  [`RouteCollectionRoute`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/RouteCollectionRoute.cs). This **route** has a collection of **sub-routes** that you can query for that includes *all* the attribute routes. But if you just want the selected route for your call, you can simple ask for it using the `RouteData.Values`:

```
var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
var subroutes = (IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData>)routeData.Values["MS_SubRoutes"];
var route = subroutes.First().Route;
```

Source: http://wildermuth.com/2013/11/12/Web_API_2_s_Attribute_Routing_Looking_Deeper

Comment: Mihai, thanks for your suggestion. It worked! But I implemented a slightly different version, as I also needed to get the namespace name used in the route. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545898/asp-net-web-api-2-attribute-routing-controller-name/19560085#19560085